# What should be passed to androidPayMode for setOptionsAsync in expo-payments-stripe?

Tags: react-native, expo, stripe-payments, google-pay

I'm trying to integrate google pay with stripe using expo(React native) by using this (https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/payments/#using-the-payments-sdk).
From the document it showed how initialization should be done as below:

```
Stripe.setOptionsAsync({
  publishableKey: 'PUBLISHABLE_KEY', // Your key
  androidPayMode: 'test', // [optional] used to set wallet environment (AndroidPay)
  merchantId: 'your_merchant_id', // [optional] used for payments with ApplePay
});
```

But not sure what should be passed to androidPayMode. Can anyone let me know what should be passed?

Answer (score 2):

Flagging that the library you're integrating is marked as deprecated at the top. You should move to Stripe's official React Native SDK instead: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native

To answer your question, the value should be `test` if you're testing in Test mode or `production` is you are taking real transactions in Live mode with your Live API keys.